# Set location.href before document has loaded but add url to window history

Tags: javascript, webkit, location, document, history

As per the spec,

> The href attribute must return the current address of the associated
>   Document object, as an absolute URL.
>
> On setting, if the Location object's associated Document object has
>   completely loaded, then the user agent must act as if the assign()
>   method had been called with the new value as its argument. Otherwise,
>   the user agent must act as if the replace() method had been called
>   with the new value as its argument.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/history.html#location

I have a page (say page "A") where the user might start interacting with the UI before the document has loaded completely and some of those interactions result in me setting some analytics values and redirecting the user (to say page "B") by

```
document.location.href = new_location;
```

However, if the user does this quickly enough, page "A" is not included in the window history at all i.e. if the user presses the "Back" button after landing on page "B", they are redirected to whatever page came before "A" (i.e. page "A" is completely skipped).

I've tried using `document.location.assign` without luck, I've tried to wrap the redirection within `$(document).ready` without luck. So, is it possible to set the `location.href` before the document has loaded but still add it to the history (instead of replacing)?

NOTE: I'm having this issue only on WebKit browsers (Chrome, Opera, Safari tested), not on Firefox.